# Checking for an email address using Journey Builder Decision Splits

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

How do i need set up my Contact Model in oder to check a *DE of email_address*.
I am working with the following constraints/rules.

1) CRM (Salesforce) allows for multiple records to have the same email_address

2) Using Salesforce Entry event to inject records in real-time.

3) I need to put duplication email address down a new Journey Path, so that the customer can take a real-time action on these duplicate records. For example, if email is found my SFMC DE, then create a task in the CRM for the sales team Admin to merge the record.

> ContactKey Look-ups fail b/c the new record has a new contactkey.
>
> all solutions I have come up with result in automation running hourly, and break my real-time requirement.

Thanks
Pat

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add your synchronised data extensions back into the contact model, as they're already part of it, so you'd need to create some sort of reference table, "email_duplicates", to do your lookup against. Here are the fields:

[image]

Create yourself an Automation with an SQL Query Activity to update this table periodically. The query's body should look like this:

```
SELECT
  email,
  COUNT(1) AS address_count
FROM
  Contact_Salesforce
GROUP BY
  email
```

Add your reference table to Contact Builder's attribute groups and link your reference table based on Contact.EmailAddress = email_duplicates.email.

[image]

Use your reference table for decision splits based on email_duplicates.email_count is not null.

[image]

Observe how new contacts with email addresses already in your Contact_Salesforce synchronised data extension go down one path and totally new contacts (based on email address) go down another:

[image]

Comment: Macca - i appreciate your detailed answer, i did everything listed and the Decision is not working.  I am going to add more details in comments below in a minute

Comment: "Not Working" in what way?

Comment: Hi @macca i just added a picture.. all of the contacts are failing the look up when they should be matching.  I have confirmed the data, its loading and the email address are there

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry, the resolution's very low. is the decision logic "email_count is not null"?

Comment: Hi Macca - apologies about the low res, i dont know why it rendered that way.. But to answer your question, i have tried various fields in the decision split (count/date/emailaddress) check to see if they are null (also tried Not Null), and every time it sends customers down the path of "no match" when the logic should find a match.

Comment: I've added screenshots for you to step through the way you've configured Contact Builder to ensure all is working as intended. I hope this helps?

Comment: thanks @macca - thats what i am doing, i found this  https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000312395&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1 which states that the decisions split will only work for when the email is in all subs.. i am testing that out. 

thanks again!

Comment: Yes. That'd make sense. These are brand new contacts we're evaluating. Try changing the relationship in Contact Builder by relating your email_duplicates.email to your Journey Data Extension's email address.

Comment: ahh - that makes sense - thanks Macca! its working now